# How to alter block configuration form in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I alter block configurations in Drupal 7?

There are some hooks like `hook_block_info_alter()` and `hook_block_view_alter()` but it seems there is not anything named "hook_block_configure_alter".

Is `hook_form_alter()` the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7).  If you are making changes specific to a single form, the latter should be used.  A good description of the two hooks can be found [HERE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/how-do-i-call-an-implementation-of-hook-form-alter/4774#4774).